# Pgfplotstable: Filter specific rows when reading from file

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

So far I have a file from which I read data to the macro `\data` (in the MWE I replaced the file with an in code table). From this table only 3 rows are selected and printed.

What I would like to achieve is to get the filtered table (with only 3 rows) back into a macro `\datafiltered`. Or the other way round just read these 3 rows from the beginning. So I look for a filter option when reading. Is there something like this?

*Some Information about the Intention: This macro should be used with two identical macros from the input of two other files and vertical concatenate them to a long table. This long table then needs to be horizontal concatenated (add columns) with an already existing table. However, I think this will be no problem as soon as I have the filtered table in a macro.*

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotstableset{
    discard if not/.style n args={4}{
        row predicate/.code={
            \def\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPd{\pgfplotstablegetelem{##1}{#1}\of}
            \expandafter\pgfplotstable@loc@TMPd\pgfplotstablename
            \edef\tempa{\pgfplotsretval}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
                        \edef\tempc{#3}
                        \edef\tempd{#4}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                            \ifx\tempa\tempc
                            \else
                                \ifx\tempa\tempd
                                \else
                                    \pgfplotstableuserowfalse
                                \fi
                            \fi
            \fi
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
\pgfplotstableread{
  num       value
  1         2
  2         5
  3         3
  4         2
  5         4
  6         1
}\data

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=semicolon,discard if not={num}{1}{2}{3}]{\data}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to output the table to a file, it could be done by `\pgfplotstablesave`. There are other candidates, such as `\pgfplotstabletranspose`.